# Multi-Index - Not able to sort multiple indexes in a single line

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, multi-index

I am trying to sort multiple indexes in Python using following code which gives me the error as provided below the code:

```
raw_data.sort_index(level='employee_id',ascending=False,inplace=True).sort_index(level='PAYCODE_ID',ascending=True,inplace=True)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-732-d2ad9fdef0b4> in <module>
----> 1 raw_data.sort_index(level='employee_id',ascending=False,inplace=True).sort_index(level='PAYCODE_ID',ascending=True,inplace=True)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sort_index'
```

I think the python results into 'None' object type after first 'sort_index' method. As per the python documentation, if the 'inplace' parameter is set to True, the return object would be a Data Frame.

[image: Documentation]

Also to note that when i split the methods into following two line of code, it stores the sorted result into the raw_data dataframe:

```
raw_data.sort_index(level='employee_id',ascending=False,inplace=True)
raw_data.sort_index(level='PAYCODE_ID',ascending=True,inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass `inplace=True` to `sort_index`, the function will operate **inplace** and returns `None`. So either remove `inplace=True` and assign back if you want to chain the commands, or do the two separate commands like you posted.

Also, you can pass multiple levels to `sort_index`

```
raw_data.sort_index(level=['employee_id', 'PAYCODE_ID'],
                    ascending=[False, True],inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thank you. I misread the documentation. :) The code you have posted worked too.